# Angular - Can't resolve all parameters for NotificationComponent (?)

Tags: angular, typescript

I know there is a lot of threads for similar bugs, but none of the solutions I have tried are working thus far. I get an error in the `notification.component.ts` saying "Can't resolve all parameters for NotificationComponent (?)" and it seems to be referring to the SwPush I am importing. I've tried adding changing `import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';`
 to `import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker/service-worker.ts';` since VSCode suggests that. The error goes away in VSCode but then SwPush doesn't seem to work or recognize when I'm using it.

`notification.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// not sure if this service worker import is correct
import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-notification',
  templateUrl: './notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification.component.css'],
})
export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  VAPID_PUBLIC =
    'XXXXXXXX';

  constructor(swPush: SwPush) {
    if (swPush.isEnabled) {
      swPush
        .requestSubscription({
          serverPublicKey: this.VAPID_PUBLIC,
        })
        .then((subscription) => {
          // send subscription to the server
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "staff-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.901.4",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "tslib": "^1.11.2",
    "web-push": "^3.4.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.19",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.4",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user/user.component';
import { OverviewComponent } from './messenger/overview/overview.component';
import { CompanyProfileComponent } from './user/company-profile/company-profile.component';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
import { NotificationComponent } from './user/notification/notification.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    OverviewComponent,
    CompanyProfileComponent,
    NotificationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue @Ryan? I've run into the same thing but it only seems to occur on my Android device. Edit: oh alright, it seems to have disappeared now... very odd.

Comment: I do have it working, VS code isn't throwing an error anymore, but unfortunately, I don't quite remember what I did. (I might've just told VScode to ignore it?) However, I did go with `import { SwPush } from '@angular/service-worker';` and my notifications work perfect